# Astropy Units equivalencies - interferometry baselines using classes and SI prefixes

Tags: astropy, units-of-measurement, astronomy

As a following of [Astropy Units equivalencies - interferometry baselines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27981489/astropy-units-equivalencies-interferometry-baselines). I would like to ask about how I can use SI prefixes for my custom-defined unit. Until now, and following the recommendations from the attached link, I made a subclass from astropy Quantity and then I have overridden the .to method.

Here is my code:

```
class uWavelength(un.Quantity):
    def __new__(cls, value, freq=None, dtype=None, copy=True, **kwargs):
        unit = un.Unit(un.def_unit('lambdas', format={'format': r'\lambda'}, prefixes=True))
        self = super().__new__(cls, value=value, unit=unit, dtype=dtype, copy=copy, **kwargs)
        self.freq = freq
        if self.freq is not None:
            self.equivalencies = self.lambdas_equivalencies()
        return self

    @property
    def freq(self):
        return self._freq

    @freq.setter
    def freq(self, val):
        if val is not None:
            self._equivalencies = self.lambdas_equivalencies(restfreq=val)
        self._freq = val

    @property
    def equivalencies(self):
        return self._equivalencies

    @equivalencies.setter
    def equivalencies(self, val):
        self._equivalencies = val

    def lambdas_equivalencies(self, restfreq=None):

        if self.freq is not None:
            restfreq_hz = self.freq.to(un.Hz, equivalencies=un.spectral())
        elif restfreq is not None:
            restfreq_hz = restfreq.to(un.Hz, equivalencies=un.spectral())
        else:
            sys.exit("Frequency not provided")
        eq = [
            (self.unit, un.s, lambda x: x / restfreq_hz, lambda x: x * restfreq_hz),
            (self.unit, un.m, lambda x: x / restfreq_hz * co.c.to(un.m / un.s).value,
             lambda x: x / co.c.to(un.m / un.s).value * restfreq_hz),
            (un.m, un.s, lambda x: x / co.c.to(un.m / un.s).value, lambda x: x * co.c.to(un.m / un.s).value),
        ]

        return eq

    def to(self, unit, restfreq=None, copy=True):
        equiv = []
        if restfreq is None:
            equiv = self.equivalencies
        else:
            equiv = self.lambdas_equivalencies(restfreq=restfreq)

        unit = un.Unit(unit)

        if copy:
            # Avoid using to_value to ensure that we make a copy. We also
            # don't want to slow down this method (esp. the scalar case).
            value = self._to_value(unit, equiv)
        else:
            # to_value only copies if necessary
            value = self.to_value(unit, equiv)
        return self._new_view(value, unit)class uWavelength(un.Quantity):
    def __new__(cls, value, freq=None, dtype=None, copy=True, **kwargs):
        unit = un.Unit(un.def_unit('lambdas', format={'format': r'\lambda'}, prefixes=True))
        self = super().__new__(cls, value=value, unit=unit, dtype=dtype, copy=copy, **kwargs)
        self.freq = freq
        if self.freq is not None:
            self.equivalencies = self.lambdas_equivalencies()
        return self

    @property
    def freq(self):
        return self._freq

    @freq.setter
    def freq(self, val):
        if val is not None:
            self._equivalencies = self.lambdas_equivalencies(restfreq=val)
        self._freq = val

    @property
    def equivalencies(self):
        return self._equivalencies

    @equivalencies.setter
    def equivalencies(self, val):
        self._equivalencies = val

    def lambdas_equivalencies(self, restfreq=None):

        if self.freq is not None:
            restfreq_hz = self.freq.to(un.Hz, equivalencies=un.spectral())
        elif restfreq is not None:
            restfreq_hz = restfreq.to(un.Hz, equivalencies=un.spectral())
        else:
            sys.exit("Frequency not provided")
        eq = [
            (self.unit, un.s, lambda x: x / restfreq_hz, lambda x: x * restfreq_hz),
            (self.unit, un.m, lambda x: x / restfreq_hz * co.c.to(un.m / un.s).value,
             lambda x: x / co.c.to(un.m / un.s).value * restfreq_hz),
            (un.m, un.s, lambda x: x / co.c.to(un.m / un.s).value, lambda x: x * co.c.to(un.m / un.s).value),
        ]

        return eq

    def to(self, unit, restfreq=None, copy=True):
        equiv = []
        if restfreq is None:
            equiv = self.equivalencies
        else:
            equiv = self.lambdas_equivalencies(restfreq=restfreq)

        unit = un.Unit(unit)

        if copy:
            # Avoid using to_value to ensure that we make a copy. We also
            # don't want to slow down this method (esp. the scalar case).
            value = self._to_value(unit, equiv)
        else:
            # to_value only copies if necessary
            value = self.to_value(unit, equiv)
        return self._new_view(value, unit)
```

However when I use the class I can only use the unit lambda, but I would like to use klambda or mega-lambda, etc. According to astropy this can be done by using the parameter `prefixes=True`, however this does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should be actually *defining* the unit inside your class's `__new__`, as it's not allowing you to actually set the unit when you instantiate a `uWavelength`.

Instead put this outside your class:

```
lambdas = u.def_unit('lambdas', format={'format': r'\lambda'})
```

Something I think the docs don't make really clear is when you use `prefixes=True` it doesn't really do anything unless you also provide a `namespace=` argument, and even then the docs don't make it super clear how to use namespaces.  I think it would be better to go with astrofrog's suggestion of explicitly declaring the prefixed units needed like:

````
klambdas = u.def_unit('kilolambdas', represents=u.CompositeUnit(1e3, [lambdas], [1]), format={'format' : r'k\lambda'})```

unless you *really* need every imaginable SI prefix, you could try:
````

lambdas = u.def_unit('lambdas', format={'format': r'\lambda'}, prefixes=True, namespace=globals())

````
and it will inject every prefixed unit into your module namespace.

Then, since you want your default unit for `uWavelength` to be `lambdas`, then both to reduce confusion, and also add some documentation of this fact (through the signature of `__new__`) specify:

```python
class uWavelength(un.Quantity):
    def __new__(cls, value, freq=None, unit=lambdas, dtype=None, copy=True, **kwargs):
````

and further, if you wanted, you could add a check like:

```py
        unit = u.Unit(unit)
        assert unit.is_equivalent(lambdas), 'unit must be equivalent to lambdas'
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have also seen that some people set namespace as: u.__dict__ - I think it's the same than globals() in this case? Another question is that this will allow me to override the method .to -> that's my goal such that I can do like (10*u.lambda).to(u.m, restfreq=203.0 * u.GHz). Maybe to do that should I subclass Unit instead of Quantity?

Comment: No, `globals()` is the global variables just in the module where you ran `def_unit`.  You could also do `u.__dict__`.

Comment: In fact, if that's your only goal, I don't think you need to mess about with subclassing `Quantity` in the first place, unless you think there's value in having additional special methods on it for your use case.  I see you've already messed around with equivalencies, so it should be sufficient to do something like `(10.u.lambda).to(u.m, equivalencies=lambda_equivalencies(restfreq=203.0 * u.GHz)) where `lambda_equivalencies` is some function that returns a list of equivalencies for the given `restfreq`.